# What does lacked substance mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean **lacked the most important ideas**?
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/substance

Gros, however, said the full text of the EU investment agreement ultimately lacked substance. He advised the Biden administration to look beyond the headlines, and see that the content of the deal, which took seven years to negotiate, changed "very little."

Source: https://edition.cnn.com/2021/02/17/economy/europe-china-united-states-trade/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cited example uses the definition...

> [**substance**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/substance) (noun) - ***importance, seriousness, or relationship to real facts***
> Example usages:
> *There is no substance in/to the allegation*
> *This new information gives substance to the stories we have heard*

...where ***to lack*** means ***to be without, not to have*** (something that *should* be present). Gros thinks the EU investment agreement contains nothing of any significance.